# Hide / Show div if checked (with remove)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to only show the `.clear` div if the `input` is checked, else hide.

How do I change the function so that if I remove checked state from the radios, the `.clear` button is hidden?

```js
$('input[name="example"]').on("change", function(e) {
  if ($(this).prop('checked', true)) {
    $(".clear")
      .css("visibility", "visible");
  } else {
    $(".clear")
      .css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
});
$('.clear').on('click', function() {
  $('input[name="example"]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```css
.clear {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clear">
  clear</div>
<input type="radio" name="example" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="example" value="yes">
```

Comment: Check the value of the radio, not whether it's checked. Based on your code it'll always be checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple, why don't you just reset to `hidden` the visibility when `.clear` is clicked?

The change listener listens to user interactions, so removing programmatically the `checked` property won't trigger it!

```js
$('input[name="example"]').on("change", function() {
  $(".clear").css("visibility", $(this).prop('checked') ? "visible" : "hidden");
});
$('.clear').on('click', function() {
  $('input[name="example"]').prop('checked', false);
  $(".clear").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

```css
.clear {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clear">
  clear</div>
<input type="radio" name="example" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="example" value="yes">
```

Comment: I can't use value because the button should appear only if a radio with the same `name` is selected.

Comment: The button? Which button?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Here, the radio doesn't have the same `name` than the `.clear` div, which have no `name`. Is your code sample complete? BTW, here, if the radio button is not selected, the div will stay hidden, because the only thing making it visible is the value `yes` selected! If it's `no` or unselected, it will be hidden.

Comment: I need the `.clear` div to only show if a radio button is selected with the name="example", and be hidden if none of these radios are selected. The `.clear` div is supposed to remove the selected state of the input which then hides the the div.

Comment: Ok, so the only thing missing here is the click on `.clear` that resets the input! Stay tuned for the edit ;)

Comment: @Taplar yep, I misunderstood the question at the beginning ;)

Comment: @KyleUnderhill you can check it back! Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just show the clear on change, and hide it on the click.  For a radio to "change", one of the values had to be selected.  And when you clear it, you know it needs to be hidden.  Logical value changes do no trigger events, so when you uncheck them in the clear, the 'change' event is not triggered.

```js
var $examples = $('input[name="example"]');
var $clear = $('.clear');

$examples.on("change", function(){
  $clear.css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$clear.on('click', function() {
  $examples.prop('checked', false);
  $clear.css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

```css
.clear {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clear">
  clear</div>
<input type="radio" name="example" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="example" value="yes">
```